# Modify const char * in C

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I am practicing for interviews. The problem Im currently stuck on is reversing a constant string in C. I know that since str2 is const, I can modify the location str2 points to, but not its value. I have a function below called reverse_const. It will reverse the const char *str_const in place and print it. However, when I try to print st2 after reversal from the main method, the string isn't reversed anymore. Its like reverse_const() is temporarily changing the memory location of str2. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *str){
    int c_size = strlen(str);
    char *c_begin = str, *c_end = str + (c_size - 1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < c_size / 2; i++){
        *c_begin ^= *c_end;
        *c_end ^= *c_begin;
        *c_begin ^= *c_end;

        c_begin++;
        c_end--;
    }
}

void reverse_const(const char *str_const){
    int c_size = strlen(str_const);
    char str[c_size];
    strcpy(str, str_const);
    char *c_begin = str, *c_end = str + (c_size - 1);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < c_size / 2; i++){
        *c_begin ^= *c_end;
        *c_end ^= *c_begin;
        *c_begin ^= *c_end;

        c_begin++;
        c_end--;
    }

    str_const = str;
    printf("%s\n", str_const);
}

int main(){
    char str1[] = "Indiana";
    char *str2 = "Kentucky";
    printf("TESTS:\nString 1 pre-reversal: %s\n", str1);
    reverse(str1);
    printf("String 1 post-reversal: %s\n", str1);
    printf("Constant string 2 pre-reversal: %s\n", str2);
    reverse_const(str2);
    printf("Constant string 2 post-reversal: %s\n", str2);
}
```

Comment: `char str[c_size];` is not enough to hold a *nul-terminated* string of length `c_size`.

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here?_ You're doing nothing to change the place `str2` points to. You already figured out that you need to change where it points to solve this problem... but context is important too! `str_const = str;` has no effect on `str2`, which is in `main()`s context.

Comment: "I can modify the location str2 points to" Not if that location is constant. A pointer is not an array or a string (and an array is not a string). Please read about pointers, arrays and string literals in a good C book.

Comment: @Olaf Maybe I should have said "I can change the address that str2 is pointing to, but not the value at the original address."?

Comment: `str2` (use markup!) does not point to an address. All you can change is its own value as given. And `str2` is still **not a string!** neither constant nor non-constant! And forget that xor-swapping, which is just more difficult to read/understand. Use a temporary variable and put that into its own function. Making it `static` will very likely make the compiler inline it automatically. This will not work slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the reversed `str2` back in `main()`, you will either need to pass an adequately sized buffer to `reverse_const` to hold the reversed string, or you will need to dynamically allocate storage for it in `reverse_const` (a local variable length array won't do):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
void reverse_const (const char **str_const)
{
    int c_size = strlen (*str_const);
    char *str = calloc (c_size + 1, sizeof *str);
    strcpy (str, *str_const);
    char *c_begin = str, *c_end = str + (c_size - 1);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < c_size / 2; i++) {
        *c_begin ^= *c_end;
        *c_end ^= *c_begin;
        *c_begin ^= *c_end;

        c_begin++;
        c_end--;
    }

    *str_const = str;
    printf ("%s\n", *str_const);
}

int main (void) {

    char str1[] = "Indiana";
    char *str2 = "Kentucky";

    printf ("TESTS:\nString 1 pre-reversal: %s\n", str1);

    reverse (str1);

    printf ("String 1 post-reversal: %s\n", str1);
    printf ("Constant string 2 pre-reversal: %s\n", str2);

    reverse_const ((const char **)&str2);

    printf ("Constant string 2 post-reversal: %s\n", str2);

    free (str2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/revconststr
TESTS:
String 1 pre-reversal: Indiana
String 1 post-reversal: anaidnI
Constant string 2 pre-reversal: Kentucky
ykcutneK
Constant string 2 post-reversal: ykcutneK
```

**Returning The Pointer**

You have an additional option to return the pointer to `str` to assign to `str2` in `main()`. This is more what you would normally expect to see. Let me know if you have any questions:

```
char *reverse_const2 (const char **str_const)
{
    int c_size = strlen (*str_const);
    char *str = calloc (c_size + 1, sizeof *str);
    strcpy (str, *str_const);
    char *c_begin = str, *c_end = str + (c_size - 1);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < c_size / 2; i++) {
        *c_begin ^= *c_end;
        *c_end ^= *c_begin;
        *c_begin ^= *c_end;

        c_begin++;
        c_end--;
    }

    //*str_const = str;
    printf ("%s\n", *str_const);

    return str;
}

int main (void)
{

    char str1[] = "Indiana";
    char *str2 = "Kentucky";

    printf ("TESTS:\nString 1 pre-reversal: %s\n", str1);

    reverse (str1);

    printf ("String 1 post-reversal: %s\n", str1);
    printf ("Constant string 2 pre-reversal: %s\n", str2);

    str2 = reverse_const2 ((const char **)&str2);

    printf ("Constant string 2 post-reversal: %s\n", str2);

    free (str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd like the `reverse_const` function a lot more if you returned the pointer to the reversed string, rather than overwrite `str2`.

Comment: Agreed, I was just working with the form of the function given and didn't know if that was subject to change.

Comment: @JohnBode - added the return as a second example.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass by arguments, the function gets a copy.  `str_const = str;` assigns to that copy. You could pass a pointer to pointer to be able change the value of a pointer outside of your function, however you're allocating the string copy on the stack, and therefore the string copy becomes invalid once you leave the scope of `reverse_const` so this wouldn't make sense here.

If you want a string copy that survives the end of the `reverse_const`, allocate the array with `malloc` or do both the allocation and the copying with `strdup`. That you have to return the `malloc'ed` pointer somehow (by a return value of via a pointer to pointer argument) and the caller will then have the responsibility to `free` that `malloc`'ed memory once it's done with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your function so that you have some way to return the argument modified.

One such solution is *pass-by-reference*:

```
void reverse_const(const char **str_const){
    const char *in = *str_const;
    char *out = malloc(strlen(in)+1);

    /* write to out */

    *str_const = out;
}
```

But a better way would be to use the return value:

```
char *reverse_const(const char *str_const){
    const char *in = str_const;
    char *out = malloc(strlen(in)+1);

    /* write to out */

    return out;
}
```

The return type could be `const char *`, but that's an unnecessary restriction since you know the returned string may be safely modified.

Note that both examples use `malloc`. Arrays cannot be passed back, in this manner, in C, as they exist on the stack and are destroyed when the function exits.

Whenever a long-running program uses `malloc`, there really ought to be a matching `free` somewhere in the code, or else you'll have a memory leak. It's a pain, but something all C programmers must master.

Comment: Any suggestion of using memory allocation without providing details of releasing that allocation is often dangerous to the reader (who likely doesn't understand dynamic allocations enough to see the full requirements).

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you modify the argument passed to `reverse_const`, but arguments in C are passed *by value* meaning that they are copied. The variable you modify in the function is a *copy* of the original pointer, changing a copy will of course not change the original.

C doesn't have *pass by reference* which is needed here, but it can be *emulated* by using pointers, in the case of your function you need to pass a pointer to the pointer, then use the dereference operator `*` to modify what the pointer to pointer points to, and use the address-of operator `&` when calling the function.