# How to use a recursive char * function to reverse a string in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

Just for full disclosure, this is a homework assignment.

I need to reverse a char string using a recursive function that accepts only a "char *string" input

I've done a lot of googling and whatnot, but just can't seem to figure it out. If I could use a void function, this would be done hours ago, but alas, that's not allowed.

The following code returns nothing, we're not allowed to change the function signature either

```
char *reverseString(char *string)
{

    if (*string =='\0') return string;

    else
    {
        return reverseString(string + 1) + *string;
    }

}
```

this is my multiple attempts at calling this function from the main to get output from it, and though the code runs, I get no output in the console

```
char Tstring[] = "TestString";
cout << reverseString(Tstring);
cout << *reverseString(Tstring);
char *answer2 = reverseString(Tstring);
cout << *answer2;
```

I'm not asking for a direct solution obviously, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this using a pointer as an input and whatnot. Any tips or nudges in the right direction are appreciated

Comment: "Write `void` function", then change it to return "`char *`" and return the input.

Comment: are you not allowed to use other functions to do the work?

Comment: `char*` strings are not concatenated with the `+` operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify const char \* in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263493/modify-const-char-in-c)

Comment: Your recursion is one that works nicely for true string objects, but not for `char*`. You need to use a different recursion, namely in-place swapping of characters.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Modify const char*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263493/modify-const-char-in-c) since that uses a void function. Unless I'm reading the problem wrong, we're not allowed to use anything outside of the recursive function's scope

Comment: Recursive solutions that are only using this function (i.e. no second helper function) are bound to be complicated, slow and inefficient. Maybe you're interpreting the requirements too strictly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it's recursive function, it should handle input like this:

1. F( "yourstring" )
2. F( "ourstring" )
3. F( "urstring" )

It prompts to handle one char each time. pseudo-code should like

```
char* F( char* input)
{
    move last char to the first;
    F(input+1);
    return input;
}
```

Working code:

```
char* reverse( char* input )
{
    int len = strlen( input );
    char tmp = input[ len - 1 ];
    if( len > 1 )
    {
        for( int i = len - 1; i > 0; i-- )
        {
            input[ i ] = input[ i - 1 ];
        }
        input[ 0 ] = tmp;
        reverse( input + 1 );
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: That won't work as written. It's pretty close though.

Comment: This algorithm won't work. The first character always gets lost while the last one remains the same.

Comment: When I say `move last char to the first` mean 'shift' whole string instead of copying value. "abc" -> "cab"

Comment: If `input` is an empty string, your solution may crash.

Comment: OP only needs a idea instead of a complete solution, right? Do I need to handle Unicode?

Comment: only problem with this code is that it repeats the second to last letter twice, need to change i>1 to i>0.

Comment: thank you, @FyrusDak. I was editing code on the fly. Updated.

Comment: well I appreciate the help, I've reversed strings using i increments and for loops quite a few times, for some reason I thought that was too "rudimentary" to be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the plus operator to concatenate char* pointers.

If you're allowed to, I'd rather take an inplace approach. Don't want to say too much here, but you can reverse a string without accessing any memory outside of the string. Your recursion could then pass pointers around.

You'll probably need a helper function

```
void reverse(char *start, char *end)
```

you're calling from your main algorithm.

*edit*: It would be a recursive solution, but the recursive call would be to the helper function rather than to the main function. Don't know whether that's allowed in your assignment. There might also be a way of making it recurse on the main function, but that'd be more complicated.

Comment: Helper is not necessary, if you wish to give up on tail calls. Remeber the last char in the string, zero it, recursive call, then restore it back. Man, I can't stop giggling at the image of the stack at the deepest point :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember the last character and then reverse the string without the shorter character.

So

```
F("yourstring") = "g" + F("yourstrin")
```

etc etc

Which fortunately can be done in place with careful use of memcpy

Comment: One question I have is, would a call from the main of the *reverseString(char *string) function only take in the first character from any string inputted?

Comment: @FyrusDak F in the case is reverseString

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work. Sorry for writing such a basic one. I am just learning C++.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
char *rev(char *s,int n,int i)
{
char t;
if(i<n/2)
{
t=s[i];
s[i]=s[n-i-1];
s[n-i-1]=t;
i++;
rev(s,n,i);
}
return s;
}
void main()
{
char *s;
cout<<"\n\tEnter a String ";
cin>>s;
int n=strlen(s);
rev(s,n,0);
cout<<"\n\tReversed String :"<<s;
getch();
}
```

Comment: Please format your code better. Also, consider rewriting your answer in standard C++ (`<iostream>` instead of `<iostream.h>`, `<cstring>` instead of `<string.h>`, no `<conio.h>` at all), etc.

Comment: My turboc3 compiler is not able to find <iostream>, <cstring> @pyon

Comment: Normally I don't suggest people to ditch old technologies just because they're old. But in this particular case, I'm going to: Please switch to a modern, standard-compliant C++ implementation, like g++ or clang. As for `<conio.h>`, it's DOS and Windows-specific, so it won't work on other systems.

Comment: Sir, what about the logic of this code ? 
Is this good , or too basic ? @pyon

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the underlying algorithm, that's why I didn't comment on that. But I would have written it like [this](http://ideone.com/ozz1NL). It's the same algorithm, but written in more idiomatic C++.

Comment: @pyon Sir, can you please follow this link and check the code i have written?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995328/are-there-any-better-methods-to-do-permutation-of-string/42348015#42348015

Answer (score -1):

```
char* reverse(char *str)
{
    static int i=0;
    static char revstr[100] = "";
   if (*str)
   {
       reverse(str+1);
       revstr[i++]=*str;
   } 
   return revstr;
}
```

Comment: What if you reversed two strings and then use the first one again? This is not a good solution.

Comment: The function is calling itself this is how it is reversing the string. And to my knowledge function calling itself is recursive. if i am wrong pls through some light